# synchronous jquery $.ajax without locking IE?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asynchronous

Spent a bit of time trying to achieve this and have a solution that I think works very well in firefox, but when testing in IE discovered that using async: false cause the browser to be locked (stops responding and apprears to have frozen) for the duration of the call.

Requirement basically as follows. I supply a series of check boxes which users may check. At a particular time I call my function 'selectedSeriesData()' which is used send requests to my service one after another getting the requested data. I specificly chose to use sync so that I could output status messages and warnings to the browser while the method is executing.

eg. "Loading data 1/3", then "Loading data 2/3", "Loading data 3/3"

Of course, I now know that this locks certain browsers so the experience in IE not only locks the browser but any messages I tried to display never got shown. Is there any sort of simple doEvents like action I can call after each ajax call has been made, or is it just a matter of restructuring my ajax calls. If that's the case, any implementation advice given my requirement?

Below is a simplified extract of code for reference.

```
function selectedSeriesData() {

    var seriesData = [];
    var index = 0;

    $.each($("input[name='idCheckBox']:checked"), function () {

        var id = $(this).val();

        $("#loadingMessage").text("Loading " + id + "...");

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                async: false,
                url: '<%: loadSeriesDataPath %>',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {
                    Id: id
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    seriesData[index] = data;
                    index++;
                },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, error) {
                    $("#warnings ul").append('<li>A communication error occured while attempting to load data for the series.</li>');

                }
            });
        }
    });
    return seriesData;
}
```

Comment: OptimusCrime, when I say lock, I mean the browser actually stops responding, and only begins responding once the loop has finished executing. So to the end user using IE, it appears like the browser has crashed.

Comment: can you provide jsFiddle example?

Comment: Why do you need synchronous XHR?!

Comment: You have discovered the *reason* why AJAX calls are asynchronous. Synchronous calls can and will lock the browser because the JS engine waits for the call to finish. Why are you not using asynchronous calls?

Comment: ThiefMaster, I explained why and I'm asking what I should be doing as this is obviously the wrong approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best answer to my question is... you're doing it wrong. I didn't have any luck with $.when as was suggested (perhaps it was due to my understanding of it), so came up with the following answer myself.

Basically, use callbacks to implement a sort of recursive queuing. This may sound obvious to all you guys, but its new to me, and I think the experienced jqueryer out there would agree with my implementation (please let me know if I'm doing it right!)

Firstly, instead of looping through my checkboxes and making ajax requests, build up an array of requests. This gets rid of the need to return my results from the original method and begins a chain of method execution evetually leading to the desired result.

```
function selectedSeriesData() {

    var requests = [];

    $.each($("input[name='somethingCheckBox']:checked"), function () {

        var id = $(this).attr('value');

        var request = {
            id: id
        };

        requests.push(request);

    });

    loadRequests(requests);
}
```

From the array of requests, start call loadRequests which initializes a recursive callback implementation to load data from my service.

```
function loadRequests(requests)
{
    $("#loader").show();
    var seriesData = [];
    loadRequestAt(requests, 0, seriesData);
}
```

the recursive method called is loadRequestAt, which keeps track of the array of requests, a specific index to load this itteration, and seriesData that is added to as the method is called. Anon methods Success used to build up my seriesData, Error used to report errors, and Complete most importantly used to begin the next itteration of requests or if all requests have been made, render results to the screen.

```
function loadRequestAt(requests, loadAtIndex, seriesData) {
    var currentRequest = requests[loadAtIndex];

    $("#loadingMessage").text("Loading " + currentRequest.id + "...");

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '<%: loadSeriesDataPath %>',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            Id: currentRequest.id
        },
        success: function(data) {
            seriesData.push(data);
        },
        error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, error) {
            $("#warnings ul").append('<li>A communication error occured while attempting to load ' + currentRequest.id'.</li>');
        },
        complete: function() {
            var nextIndex = loadAtIndex + 1;
            if (nextIndex < requests.length) {
                loadRequestAt(requests, nextIndex, seriesData);
            } else {
                $("#loader").hide();
                renderResults(seriesData);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Important lessons learned. Do use Asynchronous calls when using AJAX (Asynchronous JavaScript and XML). Do make use of anonymous callback methods provided to implement progressive queueing functionality (I'm sure there is an accepted name for this but I'm not sure of it). Hope my steps in learning helps others who are new to jquery and ajax calls. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [jQuery Deferred objects](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) to keep using asynchronous requests and then "join" the results when all of them have been finished.

```
function selectedSeriesData(cb) {
    var reqs = [];
    $("#loadingMessage").text("Loading...");
    $("input[name='idCheckBox']:checked").each(function () {
        var id = $(this).val();

        var req = $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '<%: loadSeriesDataPath %>',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                Id: id
            },
            error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, error) {
                $("#warnings ul").append('<li>A communication error occured while attempting to load data for the series.</li>');

            }
        });
        reqs.push(req);
    });
    $.when(reqs).done(function() {
        cb($.makeArray(arguments));
    });
}
```

Now you simply pass a callback to your function which will then receive an array containing all the results from the AJAX requests as soon as all of them finished successfully.

Note: The docs on `$.when` is not really clear about if it accepts a single array containing deferreds. In case it doesn't work try `$.when.apply($, reqs)` instead of `$.when(reqs)`

Comment: That sounds fantastic. I'll check it out immediatly!

Comment: Didn't have any luck with Deferred objects, not 100% sure if it was suitable for my problem. I did come up with an asyn solution which I've posted now, would be interested if the community agrees with it or not.