# jQuery AJAX Calls Crashing IE9

Tags: php, internet-explorer, jquery

My app makes many AJAX calls via jQuery back and forth to my PHP files, which gather data from my DB and return it back.

When testing the app in Google Chrome, everything works fine and the AJAX calls ***never*** fail/freeze/timeout. However, when testing in IE9, the AJAX calls will ***randomly*** fail about 5-10% of the time and freeze up IE for about 30-45 seconds. It eventually "unfreezes" and either finishes the call successfully or just fails.

Here is my jQuery:

```
var d = new Date();

$.ajax({
    url: 'forms/settings/scripts/get-client.php?_='+d.getTime(),
    dataType: 'json',
    timeout: 5000, 
    type: 'POST',
    async: false,
    success: function(data){ 
        // do something with data
    },
    error: function(x, textstatus, m){
        if(textstatus==="timeout") {
            alert("Error! Timed out in 5 seconds (forms/settings/scripts/get-client.php). Please try again.");
        }
        else {
            alert("Error! There was a problem contacting (/forms/settings/scripts/get-client.php) for processing. Contact Support! "+textstatus);
        }
    }
});
```

Here is `get-client.php` which the AJAX above is calling:

```
<?php
define('INCLUDE_CHECK',true);
require '../../../php/db_pdo_connect.php';

// set JSON array to return
$jsonArr = array('errorsExist' => "N");

try {
    // Begin a transaction, turning off autocommit
    $PDO->beginTransaction();
    // Select Client ID Length into JSON Array
    $jsonArr["clientID_len"] = $PDO->query('SELECT clientID_len FROM tbl_global_settings WHERE id = 1')->fetchColumn();
    // commit the queries
    $PDO->commit();
} 
catch (PDOException $e) {
    // Echo back JSON
    echo '{"appError": "'.$e->getMessage().'", "errorsExist":"Y"}';
    // rollback the transaction
    $PDO->rollBack();
    // End all PHP processes
    exit();
} 

// Echo back JSON array
echo json_encode($jsonArr);

?>
```

As you can see, I've set a timeout of 5 seconds which is never hit when IE freezes up. Also, I append a date/time string to the URL to prevent IE caching.

Any ideas on what could be causing this? Does IE just suck or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Is there any special reason you don't make an asyncronous call? There's a bit info over at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10243107/synchronous-jquery-ajax-without-locking-ie on how to avoid them.

Comment: JQuery adds a parameter like your underscore to get around IE's caching. It's probably in conflict with your own version. Have you tried removing that, or setting cache to true.

Comment: @Clarence: Standby... Checking on that now!

Comment: @RTB: Just tried using the built-in `cache: false` setting but still ran into the IE9 freezing issue :(

Comment: @FastTrack Have you tried without using `async: false`. Because if the request is taking longer than usual, your script a.k.a. IE stops.

Comment: @RTB: Ok, I set `async: true` and it looked like I was about to hit the freeze issue, but then my timeout error was triggered! Looks very promising! At least I can alert the user that their request timed out. But I guess the problem now is, IE9 randomly takes FOREVER to make the calls. Keep in mind this is RANDOM, most of the time it goes through fine. And this only happens in IE... no other browser that I've tested with.

Comment: @FastTrack What's weard also is that your using a `commit` and `rollback` in this case. You can't rollback a `SELECT` query because there is nothing changed.

Comment: @RTB I'll try removing the whole transaction and just use a `try/catch` - standby!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20180/discussion-between-rtb-and-fasttrack)